# Vue css variables added as inline style

Tags: css, vue.js, content-security-policy

I'm using css variables in my component and set the width of a div based on data computed in the setup()

```
setup(props) {
    const progressBar = PositionService.getProgressBar(props.position);
    const progressWidth = `${progressBar}%`;

    ...
    return { ..., progressWidth };
}
```

Then I'm using this variable as css variable.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.progress-bar-width {
  --progress-bar-width: v-bind("progressWidth");
  width: var(--progress-bar-width);
}
</style>
```

When rendering the page i noticed that an inline style is added to the html parent component resulting in

```
<a href="#/1070/applications/status/1" class="card position-relative border-gray-300 border-hover overflow-hidden h-500px" data-v-61475b35="" style="--61475b35-progressWidth:43.0613%;">.....</a>
```

The CSP is blocking inline style so this approach doesn't work.
How can I use css variables without inline style?

Answer (score 0):

It's a hacky solution but with the handicap of no inline styles it's the only thing I can think of:

Add a "style" component to your template. This will be replaced with `<style>` tags in the DOM. Inside the component add the desired CSS variable to :root

```
<component :is="`style`">
    :root { --progress-bar-width: {{ progressWidth }}; }
</component>
<div class="progress-bar-width"></div>
```

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.progress-bar-width {
  width: var(--progress-bar-width);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about use inline style?

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-inline-styles

```
<div :style="`--progress-bar-width:${progressWidth}`" >
  your component
</div>
```